# How to isolate and secure Windows Server HyperV VM running on my local PC?

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I want to isolate the hyperv vm machine network from my local machine. I do not want hyper vm machine to see what other machines are in the same network when I do IP scanning from VM.

Comment: I am asking from a networking perspective. I don't want my other machine on my home network to get compromised if my VM gets hacked/compromised. And VM is being used as a public facing server.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the VM, you connect it to a virtual switch. That virtual switch is assigned to a NIC. That NIC connects to the internet and not your local LAN.

You can connect it to the internet via a dedicated connection or any number of other mechanisms. You're simply creating a second, independent network.

If you want the VM to use your LAN and a common internet connection, you'll have to resort to using a firewall.